# Struts2 Jquery plugin chaning dropdown values holding on JSP submission

Tags: struts2, struts2-json-plugin, struts2-jquery-plugin

My question is regarding struts2 jquery plugin for chaining select boxes. I mean by default when the page jsp gets loaded values are already loaded in the dropdown. When we select a value from the first dropdown, based on the selected value the second dropdown is automatically populated through JSON. Now, I have added an onChange event for the second dropdown, on which the page gets submitted and fetch some results on JSP. But in this case the second dropdown is not holding its selected value. The dropdown events call MyAction.java (This class contains all the getters and setters for the properties used for dropdowns) and on change event for the second dropdown will call DisplayResultsAction.java ( This is entirely different action). Could you please let me know what could be the mistake in my code? Your help is greatly appreciated.

my JSp:

```
    <tr>
        <td>   
    <s:url id="remoteurl" action="loadAllZonesAction"/> 
    <sj:select 
        href="%{remoteurl}"
        requestType="POST" 
        id="zoneList" 
        onChangeTopics="getAllDistrictsByZone" 
        onSuccessTopics=""
        name="zoneId" 
        list="zones" 
        listKey="zoneId" 
        listValue="zoneName" 
        headerKey="-1" 
        headerValue="--Select--"
    />
             </td>
           <tr>

           <tr>
             <td>   
    <s:url id="remoteurl" action="loadAllDistrictsAction"/> 
    <sj:select 
        href="%{remoteurl}" 
        requestType="POST"
        id="districtList"           
        name="districtId"
        formIds="%{frmName}"
        onchange="showCenterDetails()"
        reloadTopics="getAllDistrictsByZone"
        onSuccessTopics="districtId" 
        value="districtId"
        list="districtList" 
        listKey="districtId"
        listValue="districtName" 
        headerKey="-1" 
        headerValue="--Select--"            
    />
            </td>
          <tr>
```

Comment: When you redirect to another Action, your ValueStack (bound to the request) will be lost and re-created. You have to manually pass the parameters in struts config, or put them in session, or avoid using redirectAction/chain.

Comment: @Aleksandar M, Is there any chance to pass the values from JSP as hidden params? and get them selected on page refresh?